# Problem in accessing Cart Items at onepage checkout page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, onepage-checkout, session

When I try to use get cart items in a onepage checkout block, It always leads to Allowed Memory Exhausted error. The code I am using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Even just accessing `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` leads to the same problem. The exact problem has been mentioned here http://nickwan.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/magento-deadly-loop/ but I could not find a solution to it.

I am using Magento CE 1.7.0.2 and have already tried with saving session data in file system/db.

PS: I believe this is some issue of circular reference. Suggest.

Comment: Well, how much memory does PHP have?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
$this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Instead of

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Comment: The limit is not the issue. I've tried increasing it. Accessing the session should not take so much memory. The session is anyways accessed throughout the store and there is no issue in the normal running of the website.

I'm writing a new checkout module and want to access the cart contents in my Block but I am facing this issue. While trying to debug I placed the above code directly in the existent phtml file and yet the same issue.

Comment: Can you please give me the error message? And the value of memory_limit?

Comment: It does not make a difference - Read the blog (link in the question). It is some problem in the magento core code which causes it to go in a never ending loop whenever this code is executed.

Comment: I have read the blog. Error message there is 'Allowedmemory size of 33554432 bytes'. 33554432 bytes = 32M. The minimum memory limit for magento is 256M; That's why I asked you to give me error text.

Comment: THe error message:
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 471603201 bytes)

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Tried. Did not work :(
Also while debugging I tried to access Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') in the default cart.phtml file and still gets stuck in the same infinte loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12776/discussion-between-mosiac-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)

Answer (score 0):

A direct var_dump() does not work for Varien Objects. The return value of all the functions mentioned in the above question were either tried to dump or echo.

Doing this causes the memory issue. Use the item renderers such as `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer`
to render the itemHtml() and the issue will not occur.

The issue is resolved but one question still remains that Why is it not possible to var_dump the session variable or the cart items.

Comment: Found this out while trying to resolve the bug. I guess magento really demands hard work even for simple product rendering :\

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it is valid for you

Comment: @mosiac you can use one of Varien_Object::debug() or Varien_Object::getData() methods in `var_dump` calls to dump objects data without getting memory leaks.